# Правильное чтение бинарного файла в вектор чисел

Tags: c++, файлы, ввод, вектор, байты

**Как максимально правильно (без UB, без предположений о размере типов, без предположения о размере байта) заполнить вектор `unsigned int`-ов из бинарного файла, размер которого кратен 4, порядок байтов little endian?**

Проблема с `reinterpret_cast` -- размер `unsigned int` может быть 8 байтов, тогда, насколько я понимаю, `read` будет читать файл кусочками по 8 байтов, а надо по 4 всё равно (т.е. для 12-байтового файла должен быть размер вектора 3, а не непонятно что). Правда ли это?

Проблемы с 1) читаем массив `char*`; 2) ходим с шагом 4 и суммируем байты со сдвигом -- надо в 2 раза больше памяти; `char` может быть знаковым, тогда битовые операции могут выдавать отрицательные значения. Можно ли как-то переиспользовать память буфера `char*`? Можно ли без UB `reinterpret_cast` его как `unsigned char` или сразу читать с беззнаковым типом?

Ещё видел варианты с `std::istream_iterator` в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21802936). Выглядит красиво, но не уверен, что это правильно, из-за использования `>>`.

Comment: Во-первых, `unsigned int` может быть 2 или 4 байта, но никак не 8. Во-вторых, поясните выражение *предположения о размере байта*. Какие в данном случае могут быть предположения? Уж у чего у чего, а у байта размер фиксирован.

Comment: @V-Mor 1) где сказано, что 8 не может быть? 2) размер байта может быть не равен 8 бит, т.е. он не фиксирован

Comment: Всерьёз считаете, что ваш код будет компилироваться на платформе с не 8-битным байтом?

Comment: Откуда ж такая информация про размер байта то? В какой вселенной он может быть не 8 бит? Насчёт `unsigned int`: здесь сказано https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/2.3.php и здесь https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/2.3.php и здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019 и здесь https://statelycode.blogspot.com/2018/02/c.html

Comment: Байт может быть не 8 бит только на очень уж экзотических платформах, с которыми вряд-ли кто-то из нас столкнётся.

Comment: @V-Mor, в вселенной C++ количество бит в байте не обязано равняться 8.

Comment: @V-Mor ну у меня ссылка на стандарт http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:basic.fundamental.width, где нет ограничений сверху на размер этого типа. Аналогично нет ограничений на 8 бит в байте

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл хотелось бы, чтобы код компилировался на любой платформе

Comment: В заголовке к этому стандарту написано: *Note: this is an early draft. It's known to be incomplet and incorrekt, and it has lots of bad formatting.* – *Примечание: это ранний набросок. Он известен как **неполный и неправильный**, и в нем много плохого форматирования.*

Comment: Если в файле они по 4 байта, то и использовать следует `::std::uint32_t` c гарантированным размером. Гипотетически платформа может не поддерживать такой тип - в такой ситуации пришлось бы использовать какой-ти специфичный способ (универсального решения тут быть не может). Но такой сценарий совсем не реалистичный.

Comment: @user7860670 да, именно поэтому не использую точные типы, потому что они опциональные, а использую `uint_least32_t`, который может быть `8` байтов, например. Тогда 1 способ неправильно будет работать

Comment: Наоборот - следует использовать именно точные типы, а гипотетический сценарий с ситуацией, когда `::std::uint32_t` недоступен или в байте не 8 бит или когда бит может содержать больше, чем два заначения. рассматривать только когда он у вас реально появится. Иначе это будет просто пустая трата времени.

Comment: @user7860670 я привык решать проблемы до их появления, а не после :) Вы же `::std` пишите, тут по сути та же перестраховка. То есть лучше потратить время сейчас, чем при появлении багов на какой-то машине исправлять большую кодовую базу, а перед этим ещё и понять, в чём баг

Comment: Все дело в том, что каждое решение имеет ограниченную область применения. Она может быть уже или шире, но не бесконечна. Использование `::` при обращении к символам из глобального пространства имен - это не перестраховка, а насущная необходимость, которая возникает практически в любом крупном или даже среднем проекте из-за неизбежно появляющихся сложностей с повторным использованием имен. А на какой платформе может возникнуть необходимость закладываться, что unsigned int будет 8 байт или в компиляторе не будет беззнакового целочисленного типа в 4 байта - сказать сложно.

Comment: Соответственно написание такого супер-универсального решения под любую гипотетическую платформу будет просто потерей времени и ресурсов. Overengineering, что называется. Или может у вас уже есть такая экзотическая платформа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто считайте четыре байта из файла и битовыми операциями сконструируйте из них необходимое вам значение:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>

static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8); //На всякий случай.

unsigned char buf[4];
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf[0]), sizeof(buf));
std::uint_least32_t uint32_value =
    (static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(buf[0]) << 0) + 
    (static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(buf[1]) << 8) + 
    (static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(buf[2]) << 16) + 
    (static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(buf[3]) << 24);
```

Или считываем весь файл разом, без доп. буфера, затем обрабатываем байты на месте:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>

std::size_t vect_size = ...;
std::vector<std::uint32_t> vect(vect_size, 0);
 
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vect[0]), vect.size() * sizeof(vect[0]));
if (sizeof(vect[0]) != 1)
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto val = vect[i];
        vect[i] = 0;
        for (std::size_t byte = 0; byte < sizeof(val); ++byte)
            vect[i] |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>( *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&val) + byte) ) << CHAR_BIT * byte;
    }
```

---

Способ №3, учитывающий произвольное количество бит в байте, а также возможное наличие padding bits в типе.

```
#include <limits>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
constexpr int uchars_in_int()
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer);

    //Определяем количество бит в типе T, учавствующих в value representation
    constexpr int digits_in_int = 
        std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
    //Определяем количество объектов типа unsigned char, необходимых для 
    //представления одного объекта типа T
    constexpr int res = 
        digits_in_int / std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits + 
        (digits_in_int % std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits > 0);
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
std::array<unsigned char, uchars_in_int<T>()> int_to_uchars(T value)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer);

    std::array<unsigned char, uchars_in_int<T>()> buf;

    if (buf.size() == 1)
        buf[0] = value;
    else
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i)
        {
            buf[i] = value & static_cast<unsigned char>(-1);
            value >>= std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits;
        }
    return buf;
}

template <typename T>
T uchars_to_int(std::array<unsigned char, uchars_in_int<T>()> buf)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer);
    
    if (buf.size() == 1)
        return buf[0];

    T value = 0;    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i)
        value |= static_cast<T>(buf[i]) << (std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits * i);
    return value;
}
```

В файл пишем так:

```
some_int_type value = ...;
auto buf = int_to_uchars(value);
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size());
```

Читаем из файла так:

```
std::array<unsigned char, uchars_in_int<some_int_type>()> buf;
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf[0]), buf.size());
auto value = uchars_to_int<some_int_type>(buf);
```

Для повышения производительности заводим в памяти буфер нужного размера, пишем байты в буфер, затем буфер в файл / считываем файл в буфер, восстанавливаем инты из буфера.

---

Хотелось бы увидеть пояснение от поставившего минус. Если я в чём не прав или такой код как у меня пишут только в первом классе, вы не стесняйтесь, выскажетесь :) Мне действительно интересно, как правильно сериализовать инты в бинарный файл *максимально* кроссплатформенно.

Comment: Имеется в виду на каждый элемент вектора делать отдельное чтение файла? Это очень дорого будет, смысл бинарного чтения в том, чтобы большими кусками быстро прочитать

Comment: Кстати, если я правильно понимаю, замена `0`, `8` и т.д. на `CHAR_BIT * 0`, `CHAR_BIT * 1`  и т.д. сделает этот код правильным в смысле вопроса. Останется только проблема со скоростью

Comment: @wolkor, на платформах с более чем 8-битным байтом проблема чтения может оказаться куда серьёзнее чем вы думаете. Пусть на нормальной машине вы сконструировали нормальный 4 байтный (с 8-битными байтами) файл. И передали его на машину с 40-битным байтом. Что будет из себя представлять этот файл на такой машине? Чему будет равен считанный из вашего файла байт на такой машине? Ответы на эти вопросы не специфицируются стандартом языка.

Comment: Байт в программе и байт в файле одинаковые. Но они могут быть не 8 бит. Вот это имелось в виду. В ситуации, что вы описываете, в принципе невозможно даже системные вызовы использовать, они же будут подразумевать системные байты. И невозможно узнать, а что там в файле было на самом деле

Comment: Это понятно, что они одинаковые. Что из себя будет представлять 32-битный файл после передачи его на машину с 40-битными байтами?

Comment: Система не сможет прочитать нецелый байт. Тут проблема не моей программы. В файле и в программе байт означает одно и то же. Если 16 бит, то и там и там, 40 и 32 не может быть, потому что разные числа

Comment: @wolkor, ладно, зайдём с другой стороны ;) На машине №1 байты содержат ровно 8 бит. Вы создали 4 байтный файл, хранящий следующие байты: `{0, 0, 0, 1}` и передали его на машину №2, у которой байт содержит ровно 32 бита. На машине №2 ваш файл теперь занимает всего один байт. Вы прочитали этот байт. Чему он равен?

Comment: Или в вашем случае возможность передачи файла между разными машинами не следует учитывать?

Comment: Стоит учитывать, но размер байтов у них одинаковый, хоть и необязательно 8бит

Comment: Тогда надо использовать значение `CHAR_BIT` вместо 8, в чем проблема? И читать побайтово - это не тормоз, если использовать буферизацию.

Comment: @Mikhailo проблема в 1'000 вызовов `read` с размером 4 для вектора из тысячи элементов, когда можно сделать 1 вызов с размером 4'000

Comment: @wolkor И особой разницы при буферизации вы не заметите... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::uint32_t> vec(size, 0);
 
fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vec[0]), vec.size() * sizeof(vec[0]));
```

Comment: Здесь принято давать более развернутые ответы.